# Creation of a graphical interface to save and view historical logged data

Tags: c#, database, user-interface, logging

Im working with a 3rd party system where lots of settings are saved. These are typically single numbers, but in some cases can take the form of 1D or 2D tables. Within this system there is no versioning, backup, or history for the settings. Once you change a number you cannot revert your change, or look back what the number was 2 weeks ago. I am creating something to handle this.

The data could be described like this:

```
Var_A = {1}
Var_B = {3.4}
Table_A = {2,4.5,3,10}
Table_B = {{2,5,7}{3,8,1}{2,65,106}}
```

I have a simple c# console app where I am able to pull data from this system via a websocket interface and can display data in real time in the console, or write to a simple .txt log file. With a seperate app I can also send values back to the 3rd party system.

---

What I would like to acheive:

- Save all values from the 3rd party system on demand to some sort of log/database
- View historical values - A simple interface where I can jump through time and look back at historical values. Veiwing each complete timestep is fine for a first step, but an ultimate aim would be to be able to drill down into the history of invividual values, and be able to search for when certain values changed.
- Send values back to the 3rd party system - both individual values and the entire record from any given 'save' time
- All of this should be easy to deploy on a series of windows PCs without lots of external dependancies

---

What I need help with:

- What should I look at to save the values? At most there will be in the order of several hundred 'saves' of around 50 variables per deployment - Not high frequency data. Can I use something like an .xml file? do I need a database, and if so what should I be considering with a priority on lightweight and easy to deploy?
- What librarys and projects are out there to get me started on the historical data gui? Im sure what im trying to acheive has parallels elsewhere and someone out there has already done a far better job of this than I will starting completely from scratch. Im open to all options at this stage - wpf/winforms, browser based, or other. Im most comfortable with C# and the .net world and my existing code to import and export data is C# but I'm open to picking up other options if theres a really good solution elsewhere I can leverage.

Comment: How long are you wanting to keep a log? A few months, a few years or forever? Do you want to delete the log after this time period or archive it to somewhere else? Just something to consider.

Comment: Logged data should be kept forever - But I dont anticipate more than 50 or so 'saves' per year so likely no more than several hundred in the lifetime of the system.
Being able to move logged data to another system - perhaps copy the log file to a usb and load in another system would be usefull but theres no need for any centralised backup or archiving past perhaps copying to a USB stick or network drive.